# ubuntu 13.04 can be installed from windows?

Tags: installation, 13.04, iso

Can I install ubuntu 13.04 from windows same like windows application?
I downloaded ISO file from internet. But I am not experienced how should I install ubuntu inside windows?
I dont have CD, and i prefer to do it as like window application file.

I have 32bit Windows XP in use.

suggestions?

Comment: Starting with Ubuntu 12.10 the official answer is no, since Wubi is no longer supported. If you really want to do this, try with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: read [Install Ubuntu with the Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows).

Answer (score 0):

To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com. You’ll need to download and install and follow the instructions.

Visit this link for more appropriate tutorial. -> http://teen-geeks.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-make-ubuntu-live-thumbdrive.html

1) Install this software -> http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

2) Click 'Browse' and open the ISO file you downloaded.

3) Choose the USB drive and click 'Create'.

Now connect the created USB drive while you reboot. You may have to configure Boot Device Order from BIOS setup. How to do this ? Follow the below instructions.

1) While you are booting your PC or Laptop, press del key (depends on different computers. Check for yours) to enter BIOS setup.

2) Now enter advanced BIOS featured and change boot order.

Hope this helps.... 
Remember to like the blog and post comments.
Sorry I cant post Images as my rep is low.

For images go to the first link.